# Using ViewData to pass data from Controller to View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewdata

I'm trying to pass data from a controller to view, and display these data. But after many tries I can't.

Controller code :

```
public ActionResult ValidSearch(ProductSearchParam gp)
{

    if (gp.IsCandidate)
    {
        ViewBag.abc="bob";
        List<ProductCandidate> prodClist = new List<ProductCandidate>();
        prodClist = Pcs.SearchParam(gp,0,100);
        ViewBag.total = prodClist.Count;
        return View("ValidSearchCandidate", prodClist);
    }
    else
    {
        List<Product> prodlist = new List<Product>();
        prodlist = Ps.SearchParam(gp,0,100);
        ViewBag.total = prodlist.Count;
        return View("ValidSearch", prodlist);
    }

    //return View();
}
```

View code :

```
<body>
    <div>

        <p>Bonjour @ViewBag.abc</p>
```

I've even try `TempData` or `ViewBag`, unsuccessfully.

I do not understand why the value is not getting passed to the View correctly
Can someone help me to solve this ?

Comment: `TempData` is not `ViewData`! Show how you have tried to access the `ViewData` property

Comment: Sorry about my mistake, i've tried it correctly anyway and it don't work.

Answer (score 8):

Since you have set some property on the `ViewData` on the `Controller`, you will have it available on the `ViewData` on `View`. On the other hand, you have the `TempData` which is used when you need to transfer information between requests to another route (redirects to an action). For sample:

```
public ActionResult ValidSearch(ProductSearchParam gp)
{
   List<ProductCandidate> prodClist = new List<ProductCandidate>();

   ViewData["Nom"] = "bob";

   return View("ValidSearchCandidate", prodClist);
}
```

And in the view:

```
@ViewData["Nom"].ToString()

@foreach(var prod in  Model)
{
   <li>@prod.Name</li>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, i've tried your View code and ProductCandidate is a class i made, so it's "unfindable" in the View.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ViewBag for this

Controller :

```
ViewBag.name= "bob";
```

View :

```
 <p>Bonjour @ViewBag.name</p>
```

Comment: Using .__ instead of ["__"] occurs an error in the Controller code.

Comment: that is because you are using the keyword "try".

Comment: Please use ViewBag instead of ViewData

Comment: I think you are getting confused between ViewBag and ViewData, please make sure you are using the viewBag in controller as well as in view

Comment: My mistake, i juste copy paste a wrong line. But it do not works... I've already use ViewBags/Datas, i do not understand why it's not working...

Comment: can you please share the exact code you are writing now?

Comment: I don't confuse, i'm using the same View"thing" in View and in Controller.

Comment: If it is going in the if condition. then it must work.

Comment: I do not understand why but it don't !

Answer (score 1):

In your example you've used ViewData in Controller and TempData in View

If you use ViewData["Nom"] in controller, you should use ViewData["Nom"] in view. Are you use that you are not misspelling the object?

Comment: Excuse me i did it wrong in the example, anyway it don't work if ViewData is in Controller and View.

Comment: Are you calling the ViewData inside the View or LayoutPage?

Comment: I do not really get your question, I'm calling the ViewData, on the Html (body) part of the View.

Comment: Are you sure that your Action method is not returning before attribution of ViewData? If possible, post the full code of your action

Comment: As I can see, there are 2 views: ValidSearch and ValidSearchCandidate. The ViewData["try"] exists only when ValidSearchCandidate is the chosen one. Are you that you are putting the @ViewData["try"] inside the correct view?

Answer (score 1):

Replace ViewBag["try"] to ViewData["try"] in your controller code.

And, In the else condition you have no any declaration of ViewData["try"] so
may be you have to check the ViewData before using it on your view.